# IIS Rewrite does not work for the root of an application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, url-rewriting, root

With IIS7, URL Rewrite 2 there is an MVC4 application APP on server SRV. The following rewrite should happen.

```
http://SRV/APP into http://SRV/APP/
```

I tried by creating the AddTrailingSlash rule. However, it does not work for the application's root. It does work for directories under the root, so the following rewrite is done

```
http://SRV/APP/pipapo into http://SRV/APP/pipapo/
```

What has to be done so the rewrite also works for the root?

Answer (score 1):

The following rule seems to work for me:

```
<!--Add trailing slash to root non-file url-->
<rule name="Add trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!--Match uri's missing trailing slash-->
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(.*[^/])$" />
        <!--Ignore any uri containing a period (probably a better way to do this but IsFile was not behaving as expected for me)-->
        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="(.*?)\.(.*?)" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{PATH_INFO}/" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the built in add trailing slash does not apply to directories or filenames... If you want it to apply to directories (like in the above example http(s)://srv/app), you have to modify the rule and delete the Condition that has "Type: Is Not a Directory". Don't forget to apply...

Happy URL Rewriting! :)